# The American slang term "ayyyy" and the context it encompasses, is there a German equivalent or would it just be the same?

Tags: slang

An acceptable definition: usually a word said out of excitement or happiness.

Ex.

> "Dude, I just graduated! With honors"
>
> "Ayyyy! Kick ass! I'm proud of you!"

Answer (score 4):

The ones that were suggested are not bad, but as **„ayyyy“** isn’t really a word, those come a bit closer:
- **„Uiiiii!“** or **„hui!“**

- **„Boah“** if this is a big achievement, or when you are a bit surprised
- **„wow“** is not strictly German but still common
- **„woah, nicht schlecht“** is also something you might use.

And there are a lot of other phrases that aren’t exclusively used for this context but still work especially with younger people  (**„eyyyy“**, **„jooo“**, ...)

Answer (score 2):

There are several terms used to express this in German (colloquial language). These come to my mind:

> "**Meeensch**! Ja leck mich doch! Ich bin stolz auf Dich!"
>
> "**Ja toll**! Wahnsinn! Ich bin stolz auf Dich!"
>
> "**Suuuper**! Ich kann's kaum glauben! Ich bin stolz auf Dich!"

---

It's also common to say **Hey**, but that's more or less taken from English.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this answer. The example given do not in my opinion represent Ayyyyy,  since they are not simpel exclamations. Better examples would be the ones given by GestUser272636. Like "Boah" or "joooo".

Answer (score 0):

You define **ayyyy** in the following way:

> A word said out of excitement or happiness.

In German you have several words matching this definition. Among them:

- **Wow**
- **Toll**
- **Super**

Some can even be spoken elongated as with **ayyy**:

- **Woooooooooooooow**
- (elongating **Toll** works as well, but makes the usage sarcastic)
- **Supeeeeeerrr**

Yet, what you actually seem to be asking is: What is a typical German interjection? The answer is:

- **Ejjjj** Super! Ich bin stolz auf dich!
- **Yeaaaaahhhh** Toll! Ich bin stolz auf dich!
- **Wuuuuuuhuuuuu** Klasse! Ich bin stolz auf dich!

The closest to **ayyyy** probably being the German **Ejjjj**.

As a sidenote, **ayyyy** might be used in German as well, but is usually connotated with being either a pirate or a sailor, as in: **Ayyeeee Captain!**